# Wordpress contact form 7 compare dates

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using a contact form 7 plugin. I have two dates fields - `date-from` and `date-to`. When I am clicking on `date-to`,i must calculate the difference between `date-from` and `date-to` with jquery function. If it is more than 6 months - it is ok, but if is less 6 months i must show error message. The problem is when i try to check diff dates, i catch error `DateTime is not a function` ot `strtotime is not a function`. How to check difference between `date-from` and `date-to`?

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
    <label> Date From: <span style="color: red"> * </span>
[date date-from id:date-from]</label>
   </div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
        <label> Date to: <span style="color: red"> * </span>
    [date date-to id:date-to]</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

and the jquery

```
$dateto.blur(function(datefrom, dateto){
  var date1 = new Date(2010, 6, 17);
var date2 = new Date(2013, 12, 18);
var diff = new Date(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());

console.log(diff.getUTCMonth());
});
```

// here i catch error `getTime is not a function`